# Alternatives to Google Weather API for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xml, parsing, weather

I used the article http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/29/adding-local-weather-conditions-to-your-app-part-22-accessing-googles-xml-weather-api/ to add some real basic weather features to my app, mainly the current temperature and conditions.  However, it looks like at the end of August, Google shutdown their weatherAPI and the new iGoogle doesn't use XML.  So, are there any fairly simple options out there that will allow me to get current temp and conditions for 1 set zip code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Wunderground API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/) has XML and JSON endpoints and a fairly usable free plan. I've used it myself, and quite liked it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that NOAA runs a [SOAP web service](http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/). Maybe that would be useful?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the free YQL table: [wunderground](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20wunderground.forecast%20where%20location=%27Chicago%27;&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys) or [yahoo weather](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20weather.bylocation%20where%20location=%27Chicago%27%20and%20unit=%27c%27;&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys). It speaks XML and JSON(P).